# How to avoid forced renaming properties of model into camelCase in Phalcon?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon

```
class Unit extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $ID_Unit;

    public $NameUnit;
}
```

After dealing Unit::FindFirst() in model like this i'm getting result like

```
{
      "idUnit": "1",
      "nameUnit": "m"
},
```

but i want to see

```
{
      "ID_Unit": "1",
      "NameUnit": "m"
},
```

I can do it by map in model, but there is a lot of models.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column names in the database to *ID_Unit* and *NameUnit*.

In other words,

```
public $ID_Unit;
```

must reflect the way it's written in the database.